# Print variables in java jdb debugger

Tags: java, debugging, jdb

Is it possible to view variables, passed as arguments in function, if class was compiled without debug flag? I successfully put breakpoint on call, but after that i don't know how to view arguments value.
I don't have good source code, soft is obsuficated.
Function like this: void a(int var1, boolean var2)  - so, i want print var1 & print var2.

Answer (score 8):

Compile code with `javac -g MyClass.java`.  This will allow you to watch local variables when using `jdb MyClass`

Answer (score -2):

I use [Eclipse Java debugger](http://www.eclipse.org/jdt/overview.php#JDT_DEBUG). I am able to view arguments passed to method in "Variables" view.

Checkout this tutorial links :

http://www.vogella.de/articles/EclipseDebugging/article.html

http://www.developer.com/java/other/article.php/2221711/Debugging-a-Java-Program-with-Eclipse.htm

Comment: I don't have source code, only compiled(without debug option) class. I try eclipse and can't find how to debug without source there.

Comment: You can use some decompiler like JAD , to get sources. You can install Jode plugin on eclipse for decompiling.

Comment: why negative marking ??? as per stackoverflow ethics one needs to give reason for same.